# Why is cactus ’仙人掌'

Tags: words, culture

It seems like a strange word for cactus, (hermit palm??) Is there a cultural background to this?

Comment: This spelling/word is inherited from Chinese. This might be a question for their StackExchange instead.

Comment: [The Japanese Wikipedia article](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B5%E3%83%9C%E3%83%86%E3%83%B3) explains that the spelling 仙人掌 first appears in a Chinese text in 1688. [The Wiktionary entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%82%B5%E3%83%9C%E3%83%86%E3%83%B3#Japanese) is based on the [_Nihon Kokugo Dai Jiten_ entry](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E4%BB%99%E4%BA%BA%E6%8E%8C%E3%83%BB%E8%A6%87%E7%8E%8B%E6%A8%B9-275970), which traces this term in Japanese back to roughly 1764. _(Full disclosure: I helped build out that Wiktionary entry.)_

Comment: A different edition of the NKDJ suggests that the word might be from Spanish _sapoten_, but the Royal Academia Español dictionary [includes no such word](https://dle.rae.es/sapoten). That same edition of the NKDJ also suggests that Japanese _saboten_ might be from Portuguese _sabão_ ("soap") + Japanese 手【て】 ("hand", here presumably in the more idiomatic sense of "means for getting something done").